# How to read the same book together on many iPads?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I would like to open a book and everyone will have the same view of the book when I turn pages, I want to work with my friends as a team. It would be cool if everyone could add notices.

So how can I read the same book with my friends on iPad?

Comment: ...the term `book` is misleading, it could be a handout or a video or actually anything, I want to work as a team when I do something. Anyway if I can get the book -case working, I think the other cases may follow.

Comment: Have you thought about using Airplay? I'm not familiar with it, but it sounds like some that might possibly work... just thinking out loud.

Comment: @bassplayer7 sorry cannot find anything close with Airplay from the App Store, are you sure about it? Can you paste the url?

Comment: Right. I believe you would have to purchase an Apple TV - something that may not be of interest, or not an option for you.

Comment: Airplay is for sending audio and/or video from an iOS device or Mac to an Apple TV. It doesn't work between iOS devices, so it's not likely to be useful for your purposes, unless having one iPad and everyone else reading off a TV would be useful.

Comment: Thanks @robmathers, for the insight. Airplay is certainly not something I've ever worked with - just seen it advertised, and based off of some of the pictures, wondered if it could be jerry-rigged for this situation.

Comment: Would Keynote Live work?